# Python/python3 executes in Command Prompt, but does not run correctly

Tags: python, windows, command, prompt

I've solved the issue and am posting to save others from my hours of pain.

## Problem

On Windows 10,

Python is installed in `C:\Python` and added to Environment Variables, but will not properly run programs.

Typing `python myscript.py` in CMD does not run the program but does not produce any errors.

Typing `C:\Python\python.exe myscript.py` correctly runs the code.

## Solution

Navigate to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` in CMD and type `del /f python.exe`.

## What was wrong

The file located at `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` is viewed before the Environment Variables in `PATH`. This file just opens the download page for Python in Edge.

You need to delete this file or rename it, but the items in this folder are protected by Microsoft. You get `Error 0x80070780` if you try to delete this file with file explorer. In order to delete it you need to navigate to the folder in CMD with administrator privileges and type  the above to remove this file.

I hope this helps someone.

## Edit

While the solution I originally posted seems to work for people. I would recommend the solution posted by Max:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520328/9407750

Comment: You should place the info in Q/A format. (don't answer the question in the question).

Comment: Just fix your path to put the preferred version ahead of the WindowsApps directory.

Comment: Do what the others say. This is apparently due to Microsoft being 'helpful' by making it easier to install python. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/

Answer (score 48):

Just noticed there's an additional python executable in the windowsApp folder too when running `where python`.

To remove those you can do it in the `App execution aliases` in windows setting and uncheck the python aliases.

[image]

Comment: the prompt is so easily ignored..
```
$ python --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Comment: This neat trick helped me get rid of python from the microsoft apps folder.

Answer (score 22):

Here are the screen captures starting with "Start/Settings" in Windows 10, Version 2004, OS build 19041.685, Windows Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

[image: Settings]

[image: Manage app execution aliases]

Comment: for people don't know what Max is telling. He is suggesting us to turn off the "App Installer".

Comment: @oldpride: No, what he's suggesting is tor turn of a hack that makes the DOS (yes, that thing from the late 70's that still hasn't been updated) find the correct .exe files through a hack that makes any _other_ tool that tries to find a .exe not work anymore (since they'll just find an invalid 0 byte  .exe file which needs some hidden magic to resolve it's actual location).

Seriously, this is definitely not one of MS finest moments.

Comment: @1337user what oldpride meant is that the interesting part in the screenshot is the fact that the toggle for App Installer is set to Off

Answer (score 15):

### Putting this Q/A into the right format so the question does not look open/unanswered

*Solution from original poster; tested and worked on my system*

***Solution***

In `C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` delete `python.exe`. However, because these files are protected, chances are you will get an error message when trying to delete the file. In that case, you either have to use your administrator account to delete `python.exe`, or you call a cmd-window with administrator privileges and force delete ''''rm -f C:\Users*Username*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe''''

***About the solution***

`python.exe` is not the python - executable one would believe it to be, but invokes the download page for python to be opened in the Edge browser or the Microsoft App Store. The question of "who would come up with such a sadistic thing" and "why?." shall remain unanswered at this point. Fact is that calling python executes this faux- `python.exe` before the PATH Environment Variables are invoked.

Comment: Python comes with visual studio, so why use it as an "exe".... whatever that is.

Comment: This enables using python commands from a cmd prompt. Some people coming to windows from Linux are more comfortable with a command prompt interface - at least at first.

Comment: I was able to delete `python.exe` and `python3.exe` using `Shift + Delete` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me was:

in `C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` `del /f python.exe` and `del /f python3.exe`

then turn off execution alias for python and python 3.

then go to [python 3.10.0 installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/) and download the installer needed for your OS. Open it and select the repair option and when it finish open the installer again and select the remove option.

If you were using chocolatey maybe you should also run this command in cmd/powershell with admin permissions `choco uninstall python --version=3.10.0`