# Python was not found, but i have a path to it

Tags: python, installation

I just downloaded and added a PATH to python, but my cmd still doesn't recognize it.

When I type python --version i get:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

This is very strange because when I type “Where python” it says:

```
C:\Users\nando\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\nando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

and when I type echo %path% it does show up the path (along with many other paths):

```
C:\Users\nando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
C:\Users\nando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\
```

I also have a path in my User variables, the path python makes self by installing (I selected add PATH).

What can i do so it does work?

edit: Pip does work, i tried to instal pygame without any problems.

Comment: Just a basic troubleshooting question, but you closed and re-opened the command prompt and tried again, right?

Comment: do you have: C:\Users\nando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\ added to path?

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes I have, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @RaedAli Yes, both with and without are automatically added by installation

Comment: Do you reboot??

Comment: Try `py --version` from command prompt. If that works, I suggest following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520328/12479639) method of removing the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, in my case it was just opening the Microsoft Store app instead. I suspected it had to do with the entries in my `PATH` env var causing the python executable to somehow be matched against an earlier entry, most likely some path from Windows, which turned out to be right.

The solution that worked for me:

- I moved the Python root directory to the top of the list in the `PATH` env var.