# Powershell is not reading the path I set in the users variables

Tags: python, windows, path

I set the path variable to certain folder in order to run Python 3.10 from the Powershell. However, when I write "python" in the cmd it is launching a different path where there is a file that cannot be accesed by the system.

I set the python path to this folder
[User variables path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhTuV.png)

but when I run python, the system uses a diffetent path (I run the command "Get-Command python | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition") that is in the WindowsApps folder. All the files there are 0kb and cannot be accessed by the system. I already unninstall python several times.

This is basically a summary of what is happening:

1. Finding what is running when I run "python"
2. Running that path
3. Running the path I set

```py
PS C:\Users\sfino\OneDrive\Documents\Data Science\Tutorials> Get-Command python | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
C:\Users\sfino\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
PS C:\Users\sfino\OneDrive\Documents\Data Science\Tutorials> C:\Users\sfino\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
Program 'python.exe' failed to run: The file cannot be accessed by the systemAt line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\sfino\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\sfino\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

PS C:\Users\sfino\OneDrive\Documents\Data Science\Tutorials> C:\Users\sfino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Btw, what you're showing is Powershell.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, settings, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It was a matter of the aliases as this solution suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520328/9407750

Answer (score -1):

Try executing "where python" or search for IDLE it's a default software comes with python to execute python scripts.